# copy and paste specific cell(using .find) in worksheet array using vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, copy-paste

The code below selects tabs based on the color of the tab.  Each sheet is formatted the same, they just contain different values.  I am trying to using .find and offset to find a particular cell (it corresponds with current fiscal week plus one) and then copy and paste that cell as values instead of formulas.  The code below selects the tabs needed and locates the correct cell but does not copy and paste that cell as values. I am trying to not name sheets specifically because this code will be used on multiple workbooks all with different tab names.

```
Sub freeze()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strg() As String
Dim count As Integer
count = 1

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Tab.Color = 255 Then
        ReDim Preserve strg(count) As String
        strg(count) = ws.Name
        count = count + 1
    Else
    End If

Next ws
Sheets(strg(1)).Select

Dim aCell As Range
Set aCell = Range("B9:B79").Find(What:=Worksheets("EmailTemplate").Range("A1").Value)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
Sheets(strg(1)).aCell.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select
    Selection.copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else
End If

   For I = 2 To UBound(strg)
    Sheets(strg(I)).Select False

Next I
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: I guess you get an error? Always describe the error and where it occurs. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) are some tips on how to avoid it) are some tips on how to using `.Select` etc.

Comment: I ran your code, but need more info. Can multiple sheets be Red (255)? If yes, you have no provision for using multiple sheets in your code. If you find a Red sheet, and find a match for your search, you are copying and pasting over top the same cell. Is that what you want? Also, I needed to change 'Sheets(strg(1)).aCell.Select' to simply 'aCell.Select'

Comment: Thank you for looking this over arcadeprecinct.  I don't actually get any errors.  It just will not paste as values.  The rest of the code performs as expected.

Comment: Wayne G. Dunn- Thanks for looking this over. Multiple sheets will be red.    I do want to paste values over that same cell. That cell contains a formula (looks at previous week and applies a build factor) and when I update my data set I want the value to remain and not change if the previous weeks sales change.  This preserves the forecast for all future weeks-if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn- Would you be able to explain how I would make provisions for using multiple sheets?

Comment: Can you 'Find' multiple matches in the SAME sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update #2 (Sun. 11:15 EDT) Added debug statements to assist you; Needed to add reference to 'ActiveSheet' in the 'Find'  Code will loop thru all 'Red' sheets, find a match (if any) and copy/paste values. 
Debug code will show Red tab names, search value, results, formula, value

```
Option Explicit

Sub freeze()

Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim aCell   As Range
Dim strg()  As String
Dim count   As Integer
Dim i       As Integer

count = 0

' Get each RED sheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Tab.Color = 255 Then                      ' Find only RED tabs
        Debug.Print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
        Debug.Print "Name of Red Sheet: '" & ws.Name & "'"        ' Debug...
        'ReDim Preserve strg(count + 1) As String
        'count = count + 1                           ' This code not necessary as you can just reference the ws.name
        'strg(count) = ws.Name                       ' Ditto

        Sheets(ws.Name).Select
        Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B9:B79").Find(What:=Worksheets("EmailTemplate").Range("A1").value)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(aCell.Row, aCell.column).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select      ' Offset same row, + 6 columns
            Debug.Print "Found Match for '" & Worksheets("EmailTemplate").Range("A1").value & _
                "' in: R" & aCell.Row & ":C" & aCell.column & vbTab & "Formula: '" & ActiveCell.Formula & "'; Value: '" & ActiveCell.value & "'"
            ' Weird, but was unable to use 'aCell.Select' 2nd time thru loop
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            Debug.Print "Did NOT find a match for: '" & Worksheets("EmailTemplate").Range("A1").value & "' in sheet '" & ws.Name & "'"
        End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False         ' Unselect cell
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for taking another look at this.  I do see that the copy paste is working- just not as I hoped.  It's taking the formula from one of the red tabs and pasting that to other tabs. Since each red tab will have a formula that calculates a distinct value, I am looking for a way to hardcode that specific cell across all the red tabs and keep each distinct value. To do this manually, I would select all tabs, then select the cell (it's in the same place across all tabs) and copy, paste as values.

Comment: Sorry, If I misread your original question on this.  I do really appreciate your help.  This is the first time I have dealt with array's and loops so I am still learning a lot.

Comment: Please clarify: (1) Can there be multiple matches within the same Red sheet, or only one match (i.e. you have 6 rows with matching value)? (2) Your code found all Red sheets, then set the first Red sheet as current, then searched, then copied/pasted the cell specified by the offset. Can I simply copy the value from one Red sheet and then paste in all others? (3) Will EACH Red sheet always have a match in the same cell position?

Comment: I was reading that arrays that use For Each are read-only.  I wonder if that is my issue?

Comment: 1)There will only be one match  2) No, each tab will have a formula that calculates a different value.  I just want each formula to only show the value that is solves for- so different values on each tab. 3) Yes, same cell position every time.  Thank you again

Comment: Thanks for trying, I am still having that same problem though.  I was wondering if these are the reference libraries that you have checked?  Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library, Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library, Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1  Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (Multi-dimensional) 6.0?

Comment: Yes to all references except I don't have the last one, and my ActiveX is 6.0. I replaced the code I provided with some debug statements that should help isolate the problem. Also (big also!) I found I needed to add 'ActiveSheet' to the 'Find' statement, else it gave wrong results. Debug will show Red sheet names, found/not found, search value, formula and value. Give it a try...

Comment: adding print in there helped a lot-  I was able to realize it was my reference that it was searching for that was the issue- duh!  Anyways, thank you for all your time Wayne- your a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
Sheets(strg(1)).aCell.Select
```

The sheet is already stored in the range object `aCell`. You also shouldn't use select and pasting the value is not necessary. Here is what I would do:

```
Dim aCell As Range
Set aCell = Sheets(strg(1)).Range("B9:B79").Find(What:=Worksheets("EmailTemplate").Range("A1").Value)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    aCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = aCell.Offset(0, 6).Value 
End If
```

I don't understand what you want to achieve with the second loop. `.Select` doesn't accept arguments I think?
**edit**: actually `.Select` does accept the `replace` option if applied to worksheets to extend the current selection, sorry about that!

Comment: arcadeprecinct- thanks for these suggestions- I have adjusted my code as you detailed above.  Right now the code successfully selects the correct sheets, and even selects the correct cell, however it is not pasting as values.  The value in that cell is still a formula for some reason.  The second loop is just code that I found on the internet, I assumed it was just a double check to make sure that all non red tabs are not being selected.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct- I messed with the second loop and while I don't know what it does, I do know if it's commented out only one tab is selected compared to when it's part of the code all red tabs are selected.

Comment: The code in the second loop would 'unselect' the sheet you just processed.  A better approach would be to return focus (i.e. select) the sheet you started from...